# unusual data format in web page

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, html, css

I saw this in a webpage. I was wondering if there is a tool out there that does this or is this custom made.

```
<!--
AName :: ABCD123
AnotherName :: 
MFErrorArray ::  ARRAY[2 * 120]
[1]
    [0:ErrorCode]{ }
    [1:ArrayIndex]{ }
MFErrorArray2 ::  ARRAY[3 * 60]
[1]
    [0:ErrorCode2]{ }
    [1:Substitution]{ }
    [2:ArrayIndex2]{ }
BarkType :: B
LeafType :: TREE PLANT
forest ::  ARRAY[13 * 70]
[1]
    [0:fff]{}
    [1:dfff]{B001756}
    [2:dfdf]{ACTIVE}
    [3:dfp]{12312050}
    [4:Name]{OAK.}
    [5:Ndfdf2]{}


-->
```

What is this??

Answer (score 0):

No idea what it is, but it could have been someone just commenting out a line of code but not wanting to totally remove it. Without seeing more of the HTML file I can't tell which language it might be. If I had to guess I would say JavaScript.